# Single lane bridge Synchronization using semaphores

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, semaphore

I am trying to implement Single Lane Bridge synchronization problem.
At a time, cars can go in one direction only and also the capacity of the bridge is 5.I have come up with something below.

```
int curr_direction = -1;
//curr_direction values can be -1,1 and 2.-1 means bridge is empty
int cars_count = 0; 
HANDLE sem_bridgempty;//To keep track whether the bridge is empty or not
HANDLE sem_bridgecount; //To keep track of count of cars on bridge
HANDLE mut_mutex;//For exclusive access
unsigned WINAPI enter(void *param) 
{
    int direction = *((int *)param);
    WaitForSingleObject(mut_mutex,INFINITE);
    if (curr_direction == -1)
        curr_direction = direction;
    ReleaseMutex(mut_mutex);
    WaitForSingleObject(sem_bridgecount, INFINITE);//Wait if more than 5 cars
    WaitForSingleObject(mut_mutex, INFINITE);
    if (direction == curr_direction)
    {
        cars_count++;
        std::cout << "Car with direction " << direction << " entered " << 
      GetCurrentThreadId() << std::endl;
    ReleaseMutex(mut_mutex);
    }
    else
    {
        ReleaseMutex(mut_mutex);
        WaitForSingleObject(sem_bridgempty, INFINITE);//Wait for bridge to be empty so other direction car can enter
        WaitForSingleObject(mut_mutex,INFINITE);
        curr_direction = direction;
        cars_count++;
        std::cout << "Car with direction " << direction << " entered " << GetCurrentThreadId() << std::endl;
        ReleaseMutex(mut_mutex);
    }
    return 0;
}
unsigned WINAPI exit(void *param)
{   
    WaitForSingleObject(mut_mutex, INFINITE);
    cars_count--;
    std::cout << "A Car exited " << GetCurrentThreadId() << std::endl;
    ReleaseSemaphore(sem_bridgecount, 1, NULL);
    if (cars_count == 0)
    {
        curr_direction = -1;
        std::cout << "Bridge is empty " << GetCurrentThreadId() << 
        std::endl;
        ReleaseSemaphore(sem_bridgempty, 1, NULL);
    }
    ReleaseMutex(mut_mutex);
    return 0;
 }

 int main()
{
sem_bridgecount = CreateSemaphore(NULL, 5, 5, NULL);
sem_bridgempty = CreateSemaphore(NULL, 0, 1, NULL);
sem_bridge_not_empty = CreateSemaphore(NULL, 0, 2, NULL);
mut_mutex = CreateMutex(NULL, false, NULL);
```

The synchronization does not work.When i test this i can see cars with direction`1` and `2` entering at same time.

```
  else
    {
        ReleaseMutex(mut_mutex);
        WaitForSingleObject(sem_bridgempty, INFINITE); //line 1
        WaitForSingleObject(mut_mutex, INFINITE);//line 2
```

Suppose Thread1 with direction `2` is waiting for `sem_bridge_empty`.
When the bridge becomes empty(`direction=-1`), it comes at line 2.But before it acquires `mut_mutex`, another thread with direction = `1` calls `enter` and sees `direction=-1` and enters.Now when control comes back at thread1, it also enters with `direction=2` because it is oblivious of the fact that another thread has already entered which is of different direction.
How can i bring `mut_mutex` and `sem_bridge_empty` in sync?

Comment: exit() should be called on threads inside the enter() function (with some delay to simulate the time it takes to cross the bridge), not from separate threads that are spawned in main(). Since the threads simulate your cars, why would you call exit() on any of them that have not passed through enter()?

Comment: @o_weisman Thanks a lot.I got that portion.But now i have problem with synchronization,I have updated the question.

Comment: better to ask a new question instead of "updating" an old one.

Comment: Does the assignment require you to use Semaphore?  A semaphore is a good fit for limiting the number of threads (cars) on the bridge, but it is not such a good fit for queuing up threads that are waiting for the lane to change direction.  The problem is, a Semaphore does not provide a reliable way to release _all_ of the threads that are waiting.  A `CountdownLatch` is a synchronization object that can release all threads at once, but it can only be used one time. `o.notifyAll()` is another (trickier) mechanism that can release all threads at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `WaitForSingleObject(mut_mutex)` not match `ReleaseMutex(mut_mutex)` count - you (in enter) 2 or 3 times call `ReleaseMutex` for single `WaitForSingleObject` this already critical bug. `if (direction == curr_direction)` called already outside of synchronization section - so `curr_direction` can be changed at any time.

correct solution - check and modify must be "atomic" operation - inside some critical section. so associate some *cs* with bridge, which will be guard it state. when car try enter to bridge - enter once(!) to this *cs*, decide are car can enter or need wait. exit *cs*. and if need wait - wait (of course outside *cs*). *mutex* also can be used here but use *cs* or *SRW* locks much better - because with *mutex* you will be every time enter kernel for synchronization. with cs - only when really need wait.

also you not take in account next situation - `if (direction == curr_direction)` you always enter to bridge. but what if from opposite site already waited some cars ? the side (direction) which fist enter to bridge can infinite hold it (assume infinite car stream in this direction), when another direction will be infinite wait. for solve this - need add some "traffic light" - even if carr moved in current bridge direction and exist free space on bridge - it can stop and wait, if already cars waited from opposite side.

also note how you pass parameter (direction) to thread - why by pointer but not by value ? and if this is c++ - why not encapsulate bridge logic (all it variables and synchronization objects in some struct ?

i be select next solution (with statistic):

```
struct Bridge : CRITICAL_SECTION
{
    enum { MaxPositions = 3, MaxTransitsWhenOppositeWait = 1 };

    HANDLE _hSemaphore[2];
    ULONG _nWaitCount[2];
    ULONG _nFreePositions, _nTransits;
    LONG _direction;

    //+++ statistic for test only

    struct STAT {
        ULONG _Exits[2];
        ULONG _nWaitCount[2];
        LONG _direction;
        ULONG _CarsOnBridge;
    } _stat[16];

    ULONG _i_stat, _Exits[2], _nExits;

    void CollectStat(LONG direction)
    {
        _Exits[direction]++;

        if (!(++_nExits & 0xfff))// on every 0x1000*n exit save stat
        {
            if (_i_stat)
            {
                STAT *stat = &_stat[--_i_stat];
                stat->_CarsOnBridge = MaxPositions - _nFreePositions;
                stat->_direction = direction;
                stat->_nWaitCount[0] = _nWaitCount[0];
                stat->_nWaitCount[1] = _nWaitCount[1];
                stat->_Exits[0] = _Exits[0];
                stat->_Exits[1] = _Exits[1];
            }
        }
    }

    void DumpStat()
    {
        if (ULONG i = RTL_NUMBER_OF(_stat) - _i_stat)
        {
            do 
            {
                STAT *stat = &_stat[_i_stat++];
                DbgPrint("<(+%05u, -%05u) %c%u (+%u, -%u)>\n", stat->_Exits[0], stat->_Exits[1], 
                    stat->_direction ? '-' : '+', 
                    stat->_CarsOnBridge, stat->_nWaitCount[0], stat->_nWaitCount[1]);
            } while (--i);
        }
    }

    void InitStat()
    {
        RtlZeroMemory(_Exits, sizeof(_Exits)), _nExits = 0;
        RtlZeroMemory(_stat, sizeof(_stat)), _i_stat = RTL_NUMBER_OF(_stat);
    }

    //--- statistic for test only

    void Lock() { EnterCriticalSection(this); }

    void Unlock() { LeaveCriticalSection(this); }

    Bridge()
    {
        InitializeCriticalSection(this);

        _hSemaphore[0] = 0, _hSemaphore[1] = 0;
        _nWaitCount[0] = 0, _nWaitCount[1] = 0;

        _nFreePositions = MaxPositions, _nTransits = MaxTransitsWhenOppositeWait, _direction = -1;

        InitStat();
    }

    ~Bridge()
    {
        DeleteCriticalSection(this);

        if (_hSemaphore[1]) CloseHandle(_hSemaphore[1]);

        if (_hSemaphore[0]) CloseHandle(_hSemaphore[0]);

        if (_nWaitCount[0] || _nWaitCount[1] || _nFreePositions != MaxPositions)
        {
            __debugbreak();
        }

        DumpStat();
    }

    BOOL Create()
    {
        return (_hSemaphore[0] = CreateSemaphore(0, 0, MaxPositions, 0)) &&
            (_hSemaphore[1] = CreateSemaphore(0, 0, MaxPositions, 0));
    }

    BOOL IsOppositeSideWaiting(LONG direction)
    {
        return _nWaitCount[1 - direction];
    }

    void EnterCars(LONG direction, ULONG n)
    {
        if (IsOppositeSideWaiting(direction))
        {
            _nTransits--;
        }

        _nFreePositions -= n;
    }

    void Enter(LONG direction)
    {
        BOOL bWait = FALSE;

        Lock();

        if (_direction < 0)
        {
            _direction = direction;
            goto __m0;
        }
        else if (_direction == direction && _nFreePositions && _nTransits)
        {
__m0:
            EnterCars(direction, 1);
        }
        else
        {
            bWait = TRUE;
            _nWaitCount[direction]++;
        }

        Unlock();

        if (bWait)
        {
            if (WaitForSingleObject(_hSemaphore[direction], INFINITE) != WAIT_OBJECT_0)
            {
                __debugbreak();
            }
        }
    }

    void Exit(LONG direction)
    {
        if (_direction != direction)
        {
            __debugbreak();
        }

        Lock();

        CollectStat(direction);

        if (++_nFreePositions == MaxPositions)
        {
            // bridge is empty
            _direction = -1, _nTransits = MaxTransitsWhenOppositeWait;

            // change direction if opposite side wait
            if (IsOppositeSideWaiting(direction))
            {
                direction = 1 - direction;
            }
        }

        HANDLE hSemaphore = _hSemaphore[direction];

        ULONG n = _nTransits ? min(_nWaitCount[direction], _nFreePositions) : 0;

        if (n)
        {
            _direction = direction;
            EnterCars(direction, n);
            _nWaitCount[direction] -= n;

            ReleaseSemaphore(hSemaphore, n, 0);
        }

        Unlock();
    }

} g_Bridge;

ULONG car(LONG direction)
{
    direction &= 1;// 0 or 1

    WCHAR caption[16];

    int i = 0x10000;// Number of transits

    do 
    {
        swprintf(caption, L"[%u] %08x", direction, GetCurrentThreadId());
        //MessageBoxW(0, 0, caption, MB_OK);

        SwitchToThread();// simulate wait

        g_Bridge.Enter(direction);

        SwitchToThread();// simulate wait
        //MessageBoxW(0, 0, caption, direction ? MB_ICONWARNING : MB_ICONINFORMATION);

        g_Bridge.Exit(direction);

        direction = 1 - direction;// reverse direction

    } while (--i);

    return direction;//visible thread exit code in debug window
}

void SLBT()
{
    if (g_Bridge.Create())
    {
        HANDLE hThreads[8], *phThread = hThreads, hThread;
        ULONG n = RTL_NUMBER_OF(hThreads), m = 0;
        do 
        {
            if (hThread = CreateThread(0, PAGE_SIZE, (PTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)car, (PVOID)n, 0, 0))
            {
                *phThread++ = hThread, m++;
            }
        } while (--n);

        if (m)
        {
            WaitForMultipleObjects(m, hThreads, TRUE, INFINITE);
            do 
            {
                CloseHandle(*--phThread);
            } while (--m);
        }
    }
}
```

for check how cars go on bridge i collect some stat on every n*0x1000 exits. also note that on every exit i check direction is correct : `if (_direction != direction) __debugbreak();`

some stat output: (*how many cars gone through bridge in every direction, how many cars now on bridge and it direction(+/-). and how many cars wait now*)

```
<(+32768, -32768) +3 (+2, -3)>
<(+30720, -30720) -2 (+2, -3)>
<(+28672, -28672) +3 (+2, -3)>
<(+26625, -26623) +1 (+2, -5)>
<(+24576, -24576) -3 (+3, -2)>
<(+22529, -22527) +1 (+2, -5)>
<(+20480, -20480) +2 (+3, -2)>
<(+18432, -18432) +3 (+1, -3)>
<(+16385, -16383) +1 (+2, -3)>
<(+14335, -14337) -1 (+4, -2)>
<(+12288, -12288) +3 (+2, -3)>
<(+10239, -10241) -1 (+3, -2)>
<(+08192, -08192) +2 (+3, -3)>
<(+06143, -06145) -1 (+3, -2)>
<(+04096, -04096) +3 (+2, -3)>
<(+02048, -02048) +2 (+3, -3)>
```

also you can uncomment messageboxes and reduce Number of transits for control cars in "manual" mode

of corse also can play with `MaxPositions` and `MaxTransitsWhenOppositeWait` for example when `enum { MaxPositions = 5, MaxTransitsWhenOppositeWait = 2 };`

```
<(+32766, -32770) -1 (+7, -0)>
<(+30721, -30719) -5 (+0, -1)>
<(+28674, -28670) +1 (+0, -7)>
<(+26623, -26625) +5 (+2, -0)>
<(+24574, -24578) -1 (+7, -0)>
<(+22528, -22528) -5 (+0, -0)>
<(+20479, -20481) -3 (+2, -0)>
<(+18431, -18433) +5 (+2, -1)>
<(+16383, -16385) +5 (+2, -0)>
<(+14337, -14335) -5 (+0, -2)>
<(+12290, -12286) +1 (+0, -5)>
<(+10241, -10239) -5 (+0, -2)>
<(+08190, -08194) -1 (+7, -0)>
<(+06143, -06145) -2 (+3, -1)>
<(+04096, -04096) +5 (+0, -1)>
<(+02047, -02049) -3 (+1, -0)>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd go about this rather differently.

The way I'd see the problem would be to model real life a little more closely.

There's a bridge. There's a queue at each end of the bridge where cars await entry. There's an agent (corresponding to the flag man at the end of the bridge) that can release cars from a queue.

A car (thread) that wants to cross the bridge creates an event and puts the event into the queue for crossing the bridge in whichever direction it's going. It then sleeps on the event. When it gets to the front of the queue and the agent decides to release that car, it removes the event from the queue and signals it. The car then proceeds across the bridge. When it gets to the other end, it notifies that it's leaving the bridge by doing a ReleaseSemaphore.

Each agent waits on (I believe) three factors:

1. Direction == my direction
2. There's room on the bridge
3. There's at least one car in my queue

When those occur, it releases a car from its queue, then repeats.

If you want to add a little embellishment, an agent could release the remainder of its time slice when its queue is empty (or maybe only when it stays empty for more than some short period of time).

At least to me, this seems simpler to implement, and considerably more realistic. When the bridge changes direction, we don't want to just choose five random cars to let through--we always choose those that have been waiting the longest.

If we wanted to make things even more realistic, we could make it a deque instead of a queue. Emergency vehicles (ambulance, fire truck, etc.) would go to the front of the deque instead of the back. When they arrive, the timer for the vehicles moving the other direction would expire immediately (but they'd still wait for vehicles on the bridge to exit before they entered).